# Field validation of a single button only

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have the following validator on a textbox inside a modal dialog box.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat = "server" 
                            ErrorMessage = "Role name can not be empty."
                            ControlToValidate = "tbxRoleName" />
```

It works like it should, except that the validation triggers on every other buttons OnClick handler on the aspx-page too. Since the dialog is invisible it looks like buttons just dont work on the page. My workaround is to add CausesValidation = "false" on all buttons on the page. But it is a very bad solution and I think there should be a smarter way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assign ValidationGroup to each validator and also to the button that should trigger validation (but not the the other button). Something like:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup='valGroup1' ... />

<asp:Button ValidationGroup='valGroup1' Text='I trigger validation' ... />
```

Answer (score 9):

How about setting a ValidationGroup?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

Comment: For those looking at this answer, the technique is to set the ValidationGroup property on the validators and the Button, to associate the Button with a group of validators.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use 'causesvalidation' to the button. If it is false Button will not response to Validation in aspx page.

Example:
`<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />`

Answer (score 1):

The Button has a property CausesValidation that can disable the validation for that button.
More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx